# Approach to creating an Ubuntu Appliance

Tags: software-recommendation, customization, custom-distributions

I am using the latest Desktop Ubuntu Narwhal as a redundant load balancer. This setup also needs keepalived and Crossroads XR.

This works great but now I would like to produce this as an appliance so that it is easy to deploy.

What would be the correct way to approach this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I would have a couple of recommendations, the first being on the security side;

1. Goto http://www.cisecurity.org/ and download the [security guide](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/linux/CIS_Debian_Benchmark_v1.0.pdf) for Debian and ensure the system has been hardened according to the guide.
2. For physical systems, goto <strike>http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys to create a customized version of Ubuntu based on your build requirements</strike>(development of remastersys stopped).
3. For virtualization I would create both a VMWare and OVF (Virtualbox).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is your intention with step 2 for physical systems? Create a bootable live cd of the hardened installation?